# Populating combobox with dynamic horizontal range

Tags: excel, combobox, range, userform, vba

I’m needing VBA code that will look up a value from column ‘A’ and list the adjacent horizontal non blank cells to the right in a userform combox1.

Sample Data:

```
+-----+----+----+----+---+
|  A  | B  | C  | D  | E |
+-----+----+----+----+---+
|  A1 | 63 |    | 55 | 5 |
+-----+----+----+----+---+
```

Sudo Code:

```
Sub test()
myVal = “A1”
Findme = myVal
Set match = Sheets(“Sheets1”).Range(A:A).Find(Findme)
myRange = foundRange
Userform1.Combobox.value = myRange
Exit Sub
```

In the example code above, foundRange would be the row where the value was found, plus columns ‘B’ through ‘E’, minus any blanks.

Combobox Values:

> 63 55 56

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Userform named *Userform1*, ComboBox named *ComboBox* and Button named *CommandButton1*. Like on the image below:

[image: UserForm]

Then use this code on the commandButton to populate the ComboBox:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long, c As Long
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cellFound As Range
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
Findme = "A1"
lastrow = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = ws1.Range("A:A") 'range to search
Set rng2 = rng(lastrow, 1)

        With rng
         Set cellFound = .Find(what:=Findme, After:=rng2, LookIn:=xlValues)
            If Not cellFound Is Nothing Then
                FirstAddress = cellFound.Address
                Do
                    lastcolumn = ws1.Cells(ws1.Range(cellFound.Address).Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                    For i = Range(cellFound.Address).Column + 1 To lastcolumn
                    If ws1.Cells(Range(cellFound.Address).Row, i) <> "" Then ComboBox.AddItem ws1.Cells(Range(cellFound.Address).Row, i).Value
                    Next i
                    Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
                Loop While Not cellFound Is Nothing And cellFound.Address <> FirstAddress
             End If
        End With
        
End Sub
```

This code uses the `.Find` function that you wanted to use to add item on the ComboBox `ComboBox.AddItem`. Note that the code is inside the Userform, otherwise some changes are necessary to turn it global.

After finding A1 you use its Address Row to obtain the last column. And loop through CellFound + 1Column (2 on the sample) to last column comparing if the value in different from blank. If it is different, then add to ComboBox.

```
lastcolumn = ws1.Cells(ws1.Range(cellFound.Address).Row, ws1.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = Range(cellFound.Address).Column + 1 To lastcolumn
            
If ws1.Cells(Range(cellFound.Address).Row, i) <> "" Then ComboBox.AddItem ws1.Cells(Range(cellFound.Address).Row, i).Value
Next i
```

Then Find next value and make the same thing, so the Column A can have more than one match.

```
Set cellFound = .FindNext(cellFound)
```

The `FindMe` value can be replaced by any value, such as TextBoxes or Cell.Values.

And the Range to Search `rng` can be set to the range you are using. e.g.: Your entire Worksheet

Comment: That works beautifully. Thank you, thank you, thank you!